# Django Views.py If else statement not working

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

**This is my html page**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <input type="radio" class="avg radioalign" id="DocDetails1" name="DocDetails" value="1" 
     checked> 
   <span class="RadioSpan">New Documents</span> 
   <input type="radio" class="avg radioalign" id="DocDetails2" name="DocDetails" value="2">
   <span class="RadioSpan">New Versions</span>
   <div id="AverageHours" class="col-md-12 box borderFrame make-it-slow"></div>
</div>
```

**This is my ajax**

```
$(".avg").click(function() {
                            var x = $(this).val()
                            alert(x);
                            $.ajax({
                                url : "{% url 'AverageHours' %}",
                                data : {
                                    Id : x
                                },
                                success : function(response) {
                                    alert("hy");
                                }
                            });
                        })
```

**This is my views.py**

```
def AverageHours(request):
    ID = request.GET.get('Id');
    if ID == '1':
        AgeingCheckOutQuery = connection.cursor()
        AgeingCheckOutQuery.execute("""select 10,20,30,40""")
        Results = AgeingCheckOutQuery.fetchall()
        return render(request,"Dashboard/Documents/AverageHours.html",{'values': Results})
    else :
        NewVersion = connection.cursor()
        NewVersion.execute("""select 10,80,20,10""")
        Results1 = NewVersion.fetchall()
        return render(request,"Dashboard/Documents/AverageHours.html",{'values': Results1})
```

When I Click the radio button ajax value is passed but the if condition directly goes to else part it does get the value when i return back the getting value to html page it return null value

Comment: try print the ID before the if statement `print(ID)`